# Remove SubQuery from Where clause

Tags: sql, query-optimization

```
SELECT  Q.[Id],[Xml]
    FROM [Tab1] Q 
    FULL OUTER JOIN [Tab2] D 
         ON Q.DispatcherId = D.Id
         Where ([RequestDate] IS NOT NULL)
         and RequestDate < (GETDATE() - cast ((select scd.Value from  dbo.Tab3 as scd where scd .Name like 'SpecificName' ) as int ))
                        Order By [Priority], [ExecuteDate] asc
```

Is there a way to optimise the where clause, I am targeting the select from Tab3 in the date comparaison?

PS: The difference between just hardcoding the value which the select returns is 00:00:04

Comment: the "like 'SpecificName'" is not a good idea. why don't you use =

Comment: Do you want a FULL OUTER JOIN? You don't get such result anyway with that WHERE clause.

Comment: @EstebanP. Thanks  but that's not the topic that i am asking about

Comment: @jarlh Can you please detail a bit more your remark, and i am getting the results that i need, i am just wondering how can the GetDate()...(select .. be improved

Comment: if you don't want to have the subselect (which should be no problem at all, as it will be executed once). DECLARE a variable, fill it with the scd.Value and finally use it in the WHERE clause

Comment: @EstebanP.That actually improve the execution time now the difference is only 00:00:01 . Thanks you can post as an answer and i will accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without** SUBSELECT in the WHERE-Clause:

```
    DECLARE @myValue int = cast ((SELECT scd.Value 
                                    FROM dbo.Tab3 
                                   WHERE scd .Name = 'SpecificName') as int)
            SELECT Q.[Id]
                  ,[Xml]
              FROM [Tab1] Q 
   FULL OUTER JOIN [Tab2] D 
                ON Q.DispatcherId = D.Id
             WHERE RequestDate < (GETDATE() - @myValue )
          ORDER BY [Priority], [ExecuteDate] ASC
```